# Export multiple datatables to single Excel sheet

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I need some advice on problems that i'm facing with datatables

## 1 Exporting multiple datatables to single excel sheet.

[DataTables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4sWr.png)

DataTables to single sheet

## 2 When i use the following code to maintain color formatting(Custom color instead of default colors available) in excel it's working fine. but how to keep the text in center for this particular column?

[alignment in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9HqC.png)

Thanks for your Help :)